# trying to 'npm install', getting node-gyp rebuild errors

Tags: node.js

I had to move my react-native code from another pc and when i tried to run npm install then this error will show.

related answer : How can I solve error gypgyp ERR!ERR! find VSfind VS msvs_version not set from command line or npm config?

please help me to solve this error

complete log

```js
PS C:\Users\Lenovo\Desktop\alphabot> npm install
npm WARN deprecated uglify-es@3.3.9: support for ECMAScript is superseded by `uglify-js` as of v3.13.0
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path C:\Users\Lenovo\Desktop\alphabot\node_modules\sharp
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c node-gyp rebuild
npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@7.1.2
npm ERR! gyp info using node@14.10.0 | win32 | x64
npm ERR! gyp info find Python using Python version 3.7.1 found at "C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\python.exe"
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS msvs_version was set from command line or npm config
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS - looking for Visual Studio version 2017
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS VCINSTALLDIR not set, not running in VS Command Prompt
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS could not use PowerShell to find Visual Studio 2017 or newer, try re-running with '--loglevel silly' for more details
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS looking for Visual Studio 2015
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS - not found
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS not looking for VS2013 as it is only supported up to Node.js 8
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS valid versions for msvs_version:
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS **************************************************************
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS You need to install the latest version of Visual Studio
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS including the "Desktop development with C++" workload.
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS For more information consult the documentation at:
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp#on-windows
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS **************************************************************
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS
npm ERR! gyp ERR! configure error
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack Error: Could not find any Visual Studio installation to use
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at VisualStudioFinder.fail (C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:121:47)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:74:16
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at VisualStudioFinder.findVisualStudio2013 (C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:351:14)     
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:70:14
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:372:16
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\util.js:54:7
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\util.js:33:16
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:315:5)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:314:20)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1047:16)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.18362
npm ERR! gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\Lenovo\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"       
npm ERR! gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\Lenovo\Desktop\alphabot\node_modules\sharp
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node -v v14.10.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v7.1.2
npm ERR! gyp ERR! not ok

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2021-05-15T07_25_03_795Z-debug.log
```

Comment: https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp#on-windows

Comment: The error log is _pretty_ clear, it pays to read what it has to say. To quote it directly: "You need to install the latest version of Visual Studio", and it even links you to the (above commented) URL that gives you links to everything you need to have installed. Of course, if you _have_ VS installed already, then remember to mention that in your post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I faced the same error recently. Here's how you can fix it

1. Delete the `node_modules` directory
2. Open PowerShell(not command prompt) and run `npm i`

If it doesn't work, delete `package-lock.json` and then try the above steps again.

Comment: I have same issue. tried this but didn't work

Comment: @RohitKolhey, you may have to install the MS Build Tools then. You can download the MS Visual Studio and while setting it up, it asks for the tools that you can install. Select relevant options and let it install. Once it's done, retry `npm i`